# In-order tree traversal when leftmost node has right child

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, graph-algorithm, tree-traversal

I have a tree like this:
[image]

If I do an in-order tree traversal on this tree would the output be:

> d, h, b...

or

> d, b, h...

In other words sense in-order tree traversal goes left -> root -> right, what happens when the leftmost node has a right child?

My guess is that in-order operates on subtrees and if we take d as the root of the leftmost subtree then the output should be

> d, h, b...

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, d,h,b,... is the correct order. Easy to see, because both d and h are in the left subtree of b and must therefore come before b.

Comment: What you are saying is that nodes in left subtree of a root always come before it when traversing in-order?

Comment: Yes, the recursive algorithm to traverse a (sub-)tree would recursively do the left subtree, then the root, then recursively the right subtree.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the order in which the sub-trees are going to be visited in the in-order traversal for the example tree, with a few added nodes to make it clearer (first a left subtree of a node, then the node itself, then the right subtree, in that order, for any node):

[image]

As we can see, the order of visit is `d,h,b`.

Comment: So if I pretend there is an invisible X node left of D and start there then I would get D, H, B. That makes a lot of sense. Follow up question, is this definition of in-order tree traversal wrong? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order

According to that article the end of output should be A, C, F, J, Z, G not A, J, F, Z, C, G?

Comment: The link you provided points me to a tree for which the In-order traversal:`A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I.`, which is correct.

Comment: How is that correct? Should it not visit H before G? It looks like H is the left most node in the subtree.

Comment: No , because H is a successor of G which is in the right subtree of G. Also G has no element in its left subtree. So by the order defined for in-order traversal, G will be visited first then H will be visited since it's the left child of I and then finally I will be visited. So, the order of visit is (G's left subtree) - G - (G's right subtree) = (Null) - G - ( (I's left subtree) - I - (I's right subtree))= (Null) - G - (H - I -  Null) = G - H - I. Hope it's clear now.